# How to use clj-http to post a request?

Tags: clojure

When I click the search button on [this](https://handbook.unimelb.edu.au/faces/htdocs/user/search/AdvancedSearch.jsp) page, it sends a post request. I want to do the post via cli-http. How can I do that?

```
(def default-http-opts 
    {:socket-timeout 10000
     :conn-timeout 10000
     :insecure? true
     :throw-entire-message? false})

(clj-http/post initial-url default-http-opts)
```

can post a request but the problem is that I want to pass in some parameters. These parameters(the buttons selected) are default on the page.

They are:

```
AdvancedSearchForm:CourseOrSubjectSelection=ALL_ALL
AdvancedSearchForm:GraduateLevelSelection=ALL

AdvancedSearchForm:allStudyAreas=t

AdvancedSearchForm:departmentList=

AdvancedSearchForm:facultyList=

AdvancedSearchForm:keywords=

AdvancedSearchForm:level=ALL

AdvancedSearchForm:semester=ALL

oracle.adf.faces.FORM=AdvancedSearchForm

oracle.adf.faces.STATE_TOKEN=_id21519:_id21520

source=AdvancedSearchForm:searchButton
```

The key AdvancedSearchForm:semester contains ':', so I use string as a key like this "AdvancedSearchForm:semester", is it OK in clj-http?

I do it like this:

```
(spit (file "/tmp" "ts.html") 
    (:body (http/post initial-url 
        {:form-params {"AdvancedSearchForm:CourseOrSubjectSelection" "ALL_ALL",                          "AdvancedSearchForm:GraduateLevelSelection" "ALL"}})))`
```

Actually the page it returns is indeed "Results" but no courses are listed. only the template. I want to get all the course links which are only shown by manually click. Any help?

[image: This] is the image I screenshot from Tamper Data. It shows what happens after I click the Search button. Seems like client is redirected to searchresult.jsp. I use curl to imitate that. I do it like this

`curl -D "form data..." https://handbook.unimelb.edu.au/faces/htdocs/user/search/AdvancedSearch.jsp`

Then quickly run

`curl https://handbook.unimelb.edu.au/faces/htdocs/user/search/SearchResults.jsp`

No results contents are shown though the page is downloaded.

Comment: Why you want to automate the process this specific scenario?

Comment: I want to scrap the result page.

Comment: You have to get the data in the same curl command that you post the query to! You cannot run two different requests in quick succession since they are treated as totally different from the server. What does AdvancedSearch.jsp (your first request above) return to you? A page with results or a redirect to the SearchResults-page?

Comment: curl can imitate web browser, right? I looked at the man page and find --location option can get the redirection. What's the difference with a page with results and a redirect to page? I didn't find a Location response header in firebug.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the server doesn't understand the parameters you send to it.

The escaping in use is the [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Try to check out if it get in use by using the debug functionality avail in clj-https README.md:

```
;; print request info to *out*, including request body:
(client/post "http://example.org" {:debug true :debug-body true :body "..."})
```

or try to manually run the requests either with the curl command in a terminal or with the convenient [Firefox restclient add-on](http://www.restclient.net/).

Answer (score 1):

From their GitHub page (https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http):

```
;; Send form params as a urlencoded body (POST or PUT)
(client/post "http//site.com" {:form-params {:foo "bar"}})
```

Comment: Yeah, it only scraps the page without results. Actually the page it returns is "Results" but no courses are listed. only the template. It's not the same as what I see after clicking the search button. It behaves the same as without adding :form-params part. So I thought it didn't work.